# hyperlinks become not clickable when javascript is used

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, navbar

My bootstrap Navbar is not clickable when I use javascript to highlight active link

Here is my code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
          $('.nav.navbar-nav > li').on('click', function (e) {
          e.preventDefault();
          $('.nav.navbar-nav > li').removeClass('active');
          $(this).addClass('active');
          });
</script>
```

And this is my navigation menu

```
 <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-static-top" >
  <div class="container-fluid" >

  <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
          <div class="navbar-header">
            <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
              <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
              <span class="icon-bar"></span>
              <span class="icon-bar"></span>
              <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            </button>

             <a class="navbar-brand" rel="home" href="#" title="Fidel MRP">
                <img style="max-width:85px; margin-top: -18px; background-color: grey;
                     "src="/static/img/Fidel MRP-logo.png">
            </a>
          </div>




  <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li class="active"><a href="#">Dashboard</a></li>
        <li><a href="/customer/home/">Sales</a></li>
        <li><a href="/vendor/home/">Purchase</a></li> 
        <li><a href="/item/category/list/">Inventory</a></li> 
        <li><a href="#">Manufacture</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Settings</a></li>
        <li class="devider"></li>
    </ul>


<ul class ="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
  {% if request.user.is_authenticated %}
      <li ><a href="{% url 'auth_logout' %}" %>  {{user}} Logout  </a></li>
  {% else %}
  <li ><a href="{% url 'registration_register' %}" %> Register </a></li>
       {% endif %}
  <li><div class="form">
        {% if not request.user.is_authenticated and not "/accounts/login" in request.get_full_path %}

          <form class='navbar-form navbar-right' method='POST' action='{% url "auth_login" %}'>{% csrf_token %}
              <div class='form-group'>
                  <input type='text' class='form-control' name='username' placeholder='Username' /> 
              </div>
              <div class='form-group'>
                  <input type='password' class='form-control' name='password' placeholder='Password' />
              </div>
              <button type='submit' class='btn btn-default'>Login</button>
          </form>
        {% endif %}
  </li>
</ul>
</div>
  </div><!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
</div>
</nav>
```

The problem is

I am using javascript provided to get  the visual effect on active menu item after onClick. This script works,  but the hyperlink stop working .(So I have to disable the script in order to be able to navigate)

What could be the reason and how can it be resolved?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`e.preventDefault();` is stopping the default behavior of the anchor. (navigating to the href).

Removing it will let the browser navigate to the new page when clicked.

Comment: Yes thank you , you are correct, but when I remove this line from  the script is not working and  selected menu item will not change to be active. Any ideas how can I make it work?

Comment: It probably sets the menu item to active correctly but then as it navigates to the new page it gets loaded all over and the class won't be correctly set. You could detect the path in the template and set the class (if you are using a template) correctly on the menu item before the HTML is served. Or possibly set it on page load via JavaScript by taking the current URL and applying the class to the <a> element with that URL.